# Different azure-pipelines.yml for different branches / environments

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have azure-pipelines.yml in the 'develop' branch configured to trigger CI/CD after each build. But for 'release' branch I would like to have different pipeline with different flow. 
How do I differentiate different flow in pipeline for different environments?

This is the beginning of my file.

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These packages should be suitable for deployment to any environment, including production. Do not configure branches or builds so that each environment is built separately. - *.NET DevOps for Azure by Jeffrey Palermo*

As I understand, they recommend to make one package and deploy same package to different environments.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what you want to do exactly, you can either use conditions:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  # obviously you'd need to put conditions on all the steps
```

or you can just create an entirely different pipeline and have that trigger on master only.

I think this will also work:

```
steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  - powershell: 'get-process'
```

this way you can put multiple tasks under the same `if`.

Comment: How I can change 'trigger' section?

Comment: depends on what you want to change, but I dont think conditions are supported for triggers, so it shall be static\hardcoded

Comment: So if I want to have different azure-pipelines.yml for different branches I should manage it in git, rather then having something like azure-pipelines.dev.yml or azure-pipelines.prod.yml for different cases. What is the best practice?

Comment: well, i usually have a single build and you can choose what branch to build when you start the build, but if you need different steps on different branches you'd need to put conditions